# Why aren't the references for a Thesis sorted as per order of usage in PdfLatex?

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I've explained my problems in the end

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PTC}
\caption{Solar Thermal energy collection devices \cite{quaschning2003solar}}
\label{PTC}
\end{figure}

*Wall of code without any float*

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=317pt,keepaspectratio]{LCOE}
\caption{U.S. average levelized costs (2011 \$/MWh) for plants entering service in 2018\cite{website:http://www.eia.gov/}}
\end{table}
```

I've made the references section in the end. I'm using PdfLatex on normal mode.

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibfile}{}
```

Two problems :

1) PdfLatex doesn't seem sensitive to changes in bibliography style

2) Even while using bibliography style as unsorted, the references aren't ordered as per first usage. In this case, the reference for the table is marked as [1] in the output while the figure is marked as [2]. What can be the possible problem?

Comment: Try to run again `bibtex`.

Comment: The reference number problem might have to do with a "table of figures"/"table of tables". The caption will be reprinted there, and if the tables are listed before the figures, the table will have the first occurrence. (Just a guess, without a full MWE it is hard to say, really. Also make sure to run the sequence of `pdlfatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`)

Comment: Hi! Please make your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.